# Java Swing Maximize button of JFrame disappearss

Tags: java, swing

I have created a java frame. It contains a JSplitPane. In the right partition of the splitpane , I have put JTextPane. Now I have kept JButton somewhere on the frame. When I click the button, a new JTextArea is inserted in the JTextPane as follows

```
JTextArea newTextBox = new JTextArea(1, 1);
StyleConstants.setComponent(style, newTextBox);
```

My problem is as soon as I insert JTextArea in JTextPane, the maximize button of my JFrame disappears. Can anyone tell me what could be the reason of happning this.

Comment: Can you post some compilable code that demonstrates this?

Answer (score 1):

Maxmize button is unavailable on two conditions:

1. For a Dialog, in which case only close(X) button is availabe.
2. If frame.setResizable(false) has been called(i.e diabled resize of window)

So applying this to your case, my best guess is that somewhere in your button's action you may have made it unresizable.

Comment: thank you so much for reply ... your guess is correct. I have removed it and my code is working fine.